How to replace a where condition by another in Hot Chocolate?
I'm using Hot Chocolate to query peoples:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SageApi.Model.Sage;

public partial class People
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = null!;

    public int? Age { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }


    public static void ConfigureModelBuilder(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<People>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id, "UKA_PEOPLE_Id").IsUnique();
            entity.Property(e => e.Age).HasColumnName("Age");
            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        });
    }
}

What I want to do ?
I want the people who use my API to be able to query the peoples who are over 21 years old without having to specify the age 21 (this is a simplify example of what I want to do, to keep it simple).
Something like:
{
    peoples(where: { aboveAge: { eq: true } }) {
        items {
            id
            age
            name
        }
    }
}

What I tried
So I added a field AboveAge in People like so (this way I can query this field even if this field doesn't exists in the bdd):
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    // ...
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    
    [IsProjected(false)] [NotMapped] public virtual bool? AboveAge { get; set; }

    public static void ConfigureModelBuilder(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    // ...

In my Query.cs, I use UseOffsetPaging, UseProjection, UseFiltering, UseSorting and my custom UseAboveAgeFilter to modify the query before UseFiltering is called
public class Query
{
    [UseOffsetPaging(MaxPageSize = 100, IncludeTotalCount = true, DefaultPageSize = 20)]
    [UseProjection]
    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    [UseAboveAgeFilter]
    public IEnumerable<People> GetPeoples([Service] AppDbContext context) =>
        context.Peoples;
}

In my UseAboveAgeFilter.cs:
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using HotChocolate.Types.Descriptors;
using SageApi.Model.Sage;

namespace SageApi.Services.GraphQl.Middleware;

public class UseAboveAgeFilterAttribute : ObjectFieldDescriptorAttribute
{
    public UseAboveAgeFilterAttribute([CallerLineNumber] int order = 0)
    {
        Order = order;
    }

    protected override void OnConfigure(
        IDescriptorContext context,
        IObjectFieldDescriptor descriptor,
        MemberInfo member
    )
    {
        descriptor.Use(next => async middlewareContext =>
        {
            // can I modify the middlewareContext in a way that I remove aboveAge param and replace it
            // with age >= 21, this way the UseFiltering Middleware will work as intended when it will
            // be called after ?
            await next(middlewareContext);
            object? result = middlewareContext.Result;
            if (result is InternalDbSet<People> dbSet)
            {
                // or can I do it here ?
            }
        });
    }
}

I want to modify the middlewareContext by removing the aboveAge = true condition and replace it with age >= 21 condition but I can't find a way to it. If I can do that in my Middleware UseAboveAgeFilter which is call before all the Hot Chocolate Middleware it should work.
When I try to query I got error (which is normal, as I didn't modify the middlewareContext to remove aboveAge = true condition and replace it with age >= 21):
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Unexpected Execution Error",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 5
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "peoples"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "message": "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<People>()\r\n    .Where(f => f.AboveAge == __p_0)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of member 'AboveAge' on entity type 'People' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.",
                "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)\r\n   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.QueryableOffsetPagingHandler`1.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ResolveAsync>b__0()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__281_0(Object obj)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.QueryableOffsetPagingHandler`1.ResolveAsync(IResolverContext context, IQueryable`1 source, OffsetPagingArguments arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.OffsetPagingHandler.HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.IPagingHandler.SliceAsync(IResolverContext context, Object source)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.PagingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(IMiddlewareContext context)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Utilities.MiddlewareCompiler`1.ExpressionHelper.AwaitTaskHelper(Task task)\r\n   at SageApi.Services.GraphQl.Middleware.UseFDocenteteMappingAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<<OnConfigure>b__1>d.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\sagealexandrehome\\Documents\\SageApi\\SageApi\\Services\\GraphQl\\Middleware\\UseFDocenteteMappingAttribute.cs:line 26\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.ExecuteResolverPipelineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.TryExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "peoples": null
    }
}

Question
Am I on the right path to solve this problem ?
If yes, how can I continue ?
If no, what can I try ?

The question's code is convoluted, mixing up DbContext configuration inside entities. The easy way is to just add a filter to the LINQ query, eg public IQueryable<People> GetPeoples([Service] AppDbContext context) => context.Peoples.Where(p=>p.Age>=_someSetting);. I changed the return type to IQueryable too, otherwise this method will load all matching results in memory, then apply the rest of the GraphQL operators to the in-memory objects.

You need to go through the middlewareContext.Selection.Arguments and replace the argument you need by another:
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using HotChocolate.Language;
using HotChocolate.Resolvers;
using HotChocolate.Types.Descriptors;

namespace SageApi.Services.GraphQl.Middleware;

public class UseAboveAgeFilterAttribute : ObjectFieldDescriptorAttribute
{
    public UseAboveAgeFilterAttribute([CallerLineNumber] int order = 0)
    {
        Order = order;
    }

    protected override void OnConfigure(
        IDescriptorContext context,
        IObjectFieldDescriptor descriptor,
        MemberInfo member
    )
    {
        descriptor.Use(next => async middlewareContext =>
        {
            await next(middlewareContext);
            var arguments = middlewareContext.Selection.Arguments;
            foreach (var argument in arguments)
            {
                if (argument.Name == "where")
                {
                    var objectFieldNodes = (List<ObjectFieldNode>)argument.ValueLiteral?.Value;
                    foreach (var objectFieldNode in objectFieldNodes.ToList())
                    {
                        if (objectFieldNode.Name.Value == "aboveAge")
                        {
                            objectFieldNodes.Remove(objectFieldNode);// remove above age
                            
                            // add age >= 21
                            var newObjectFieldNode = new ObjectFieldNode(
                                "age",
                                new ObjectValueNode(new List<ObjectFieldNode>
                                {
                                    new("gte", new IntValueNode(21))
                                })
                            );
                            objectFieldNodes.Add(newObjectFieldNode);
                        }
                    }

                    middlewareContext.ReplaceArgument("where", new ArgumentValue(
                        argument,
                        argument.Kind ?? ValueKind.Object,
                        argument.IsFullyCoerced,
                        argument.IsDefaultValue,
                        argument.Value,
                        new ObjectValueNode(objectFieldNodes)
                    ));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```


There's no reason for this. You can just add a .Where to the LINQ query that feeds the GraphQL query (eg return context.Peoples.Where(p=>p.Age>=someValue) )or you can map to a view. The question's code is rather convoluted and simply not necessary, including what looks like DbContext configuration inside an entity, while the error itself complains about an invalid query that's not shown anywhere in the question

I know that I can edit the LINQ query to add a Where the problem is I also need to remove the where aboveAge = true and this where is added by the UseFiltering provided by HotChocolate. And I didn't find a way to remove a Where condition in an already built LINQ query

I only downvoted the bad answer. The question itself isn't good either, but I didn't downvote it. It shows a lot of partial and convoluted code and doesn't even show the code that raises the error. The error complains about .Where(f => f.AboveAge == __p_0)

find a way to remove a Where you want to add a clause, not remove it. You don't have to remove one clause to add another. Every LINQ operator returns a new query ie IQueryable instance. You can chain multiple .Where clauses together in code. The GraphQL operators will be applied to to the IQueryable returned by GetPeople, no matter what it is. This allows you to add any filters you want

doesn't even show the code that raises the error I cannot show the code that raise the error because it's not part of my project. The code which add .Where(f => f.AboveAge == __p_0) is in the middleware UseFiltering.

UseFiltering tells HotChocolate that filtering is allowed, it doesn't filter itself. I now see that [NotMapped] public virtual bool? AboveAge tells EF to not map that property, which means it can't be used in any query. That line appears in a snippet that doesn't contain any entity definitions. I had to search in the page to find AboveAge

it doesn't filter itself yes it does, first paragraph of documentation https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/fetching-data/filtering/#binding-of-filtertypes The default filter implementation translates filters to expression trees that are applied to IQueryable.

Are you willing to continue this discussion in a meetup ? As I'm having a hard time to anderstand how your solution would work.
